# Google sheet script : Delete row depending on column content

Tags: google-sheets

I am pretty new to Google script and learning right now. I have read many topics on this but did not manage to make my code work so I am posting here :)

I am trying to delete rows that contains a specific value among other text ("housse" in this example) in the 3rd column.
Here is what I have done so far, does anyone know what I am missing ?

```
// Delete rows depending on Column content
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (row[2].indexOf("housse") > 0) {
      sheet.deleteRows((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things, I started from the bottom which let me delete a row at a time without worrying about what was already gone. Also, indexOf would need to be > -1.Also you need `deleteRow` not `deleteRows`.
I know what you were thinking, but I think your logic would still fail if housse occurred in consecutive rows, say 17 and 18. You would delete row 17, row 18 would become row 17, and you would never look at it. A `while` rather than `for` could make it right, but starting from the bottom is simpler.

After those fixes, it seems to work nicely.

```
 function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var i = numRows-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (String(row[2]).indexOf("housse")>-1) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
};
```

or with `includes`:

```
   function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var i = numRows-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (String(row[2]).includes("housse")) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
};
```

REVISION:
and here is an adaptation for performance on the large scale based on what you posted you were trying (based on the helpful article at https://yagisanatode.com/2019/06/12/google-apps-script-delete-rows-based-on-a-columns-cell-value-in-google-sheet/). It worked for me. Notice that the searched-for item in our case is a string, not a number, and we need need to be working on a string if we say indexOf. toString() keeps it from being an error if some other type of data is in that cell in that column.

```
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
var VALUES = RANGE.getValues();
var DELETE_VAL = "housse"; // a string
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 6; //Zero is first

function myFunction() {
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  var newRangeVals = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
    if (rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH].toString().indexOf(DELETE_VAL) == -1){// text to avoid not found      
      newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);
    };
  };
  
  RANGE.clearContent();
  
  var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
  newRange.setValues(newRangeVals); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this !! It works well and I am changing my other scripts to start for the end as well. I did not know that :) 

My script is reaching execution time as this sheet has a lot of rows (+80k), is there any way to make script faster or go around Google Sheets timeout ?

Comment: see https://yagisanatode.com/2019/06/12/google-apps-script-delete-rows-based-on-a-columns-cell-value-in-google-sheet/. The trick is to work on the range and then repace the sheet contents once, rather than working on the sheet line by line

Comment: Thank you, I am trying that right now but I cannot figure out how to make this work with contains instead of =
I am putting the code bellow

Comment: how about rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH].indexOf( DELETE_VAL)==-1?

Comment: Yes I tried that before but had the following error : "TypeError: rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH].indexOf is not a function"

Comment: what if you say TEXT( rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH]).indexOf( DELETE_VAL) to cast it to a string first?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I tried many things in the past hours, I come up with this (see answer bellow), the script run correctly but do not delete the rows. If you have any idea I would be happy to read them ! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried :

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
var VALUES = RANGE.getValues();
var DELETE_VAL = VALUES.indexOf("Accessoires");
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 6; //Zero is first

function main() {
  
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: "+runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){
  
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  var newRangeVals = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] !=DELETE_VAL){
      
      newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);
    };
  };
  
  RANGE.clearContent();
  
  var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
  newRange.setValues(newRangeVals);
};
```

Comment: maybe it's not deleting because there are no exact matches. You could do one of three things. see if countif(just that cell,"*"+"housse"+* is 0 or 1, or try rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH]).text().indexOf( DELETE_VAL)==-1 or make a regular expression of "housse" and see if it matches. Sorry, that's all I have time for now. At this point, I think maybe this is a different question you could post separately?

Comment: your delete_val will be a number in this scenario. I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: I have created a new topic for this. Thank you again for your time and your help, I really appreciate it !

Comment: ok, but if you look above, I think I fixed it.

Comment: but I answered it there too. If you want to delete that one, that's fine with me.